# Why JCL encountered error IGYWCL expansion

Tags: writefile, jcl

I wrote a cobol code to add record to a file and I runed it using jcl but encounterd an error. The error message is:
´´ procedure IGYWCL was expanded using system library sys1.proclib ´´.

How can i fix this error.

Comment: If you are interested in an answer, please post details. The JCL and joblog at minimum.

Comment: The message is informational and not an error. It merely indicates that a JCL procedure was used. There must be additional messages indicating your error.